# Why scrollrectToVisible doesn't work when keyboard appears?

Tags: ios, swift

In code I have something like this which is called when keyboard did appear on the screen.

```
scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(blikCodeView.frame, animated: true)
```

Although `blikCodeView` is not visible at all (as of it is covered by currently presented keyboard), it is not scrolled up to make it visible. Why?

Comment: means it's scroll but covered by keyboard ?

Comment: yes, why the vie doesnt move up to be visible? constraints are done correctly once keyboard appears because I can scroll it up manuallly and view is visible

Comment: did you try `setcontentoffset`?

Comment: or you can use `IQKeyboardManager` and enable in app delegate it will handle automatic.

Comment: check edit one and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    let rScreenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height - 260//keyboard height as 8 & SE
    let newY = rScreenHeight - txt.frame.height - 16
    let y = scrollView.height - newY
    let newOffSet = CGPoint(x: 0, y: y)
    scrollView.setContentOffset(newOffSet, animated: true)
```

**NOTE** : here i set `txtField.autocorectionType = .no`

Comment: No, it cant be content offset, because this way it may be set too much up...

Comment: you need to perform one time calculation let me try to complete it.

Comment: Don't use absolute values for keyboard sizes.  Listen for the notifications that are generated by the keyboard showing/hiding, and use the size info they give to set the offset.

Comment: @flanker i know that it just for example